# Does google automl do image augmentation automatically?

Tags: automl, google-cloud-automl

I am using automl from google using a custom dataset.  The dataset consists of images collected by me.  However, manually labelling the image take some time, so I would like to enlarge the dataset by image augmentation, such as rotation and blurring.  Does automl perform augmentation behind the screen automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoML does few types of data augmentation. This is implementation detail and may change in the future without notice, basic augmentations that are used are:

- random resizes / crops
- random flip left right
- random color and brightness distortions
- more may be used / added in the future

If doing data augmentation on your side please follow best practices:

- if you augment image - please put all augmentations of the same image in the same part of the dataset (TRAIN, VALIDATION, TEST) - otherwise the model can overfit without noticing (if almost the same image is in TRAIN and VALIDATION set)
- do transformations that are meaningful in your context - for example rotations - if in typical use-case you don't get rotated images or objects that are rotated - then training model to detect rotated images may not help your application (for example if you never see people who are upside down in your real application - than training with people who are upside down may not benefit your end model).

Comment: Can you please share the link to this implementation or documentation? How can one track the augmentation approaches they do behind the scenes and across versions